# Unresolved Reference Kotlinx in IntellijIdea. Even after adding the library

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlinx

I just wanted to taste Kotlin coroutines. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to use the library `kotlinx` in `IntelliJ`. I have downloaded the library through `Maven`.

1. Tried invalidating caches.
2. Rebuilt project.
3. Tried using it in a fresh project.
4. Even `IntelliJ` is suggesting `kotlinx` in auto-completion.
5. Still it says unresolved reference

I have tried most of the solutions on the web. But nothing worked.

Here are the steps that I am exactly doing.

[image: made a new project]

Made a new project.

[image]

`kotlinx` is underlined since the library has not been added.

[image]

In `project structure > modules > dependencies > add > library > maven` Searched for the `kotlinx` library.

[image]

Downloaded the library.

[image]

Applied the settings.

[image]

`kotlinx` library is now visible in the `External Libraries` section.

[image]

Even the auto-completion is now suggesting `kotlinx`.

[image]

Still, nothing changes. The result is the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found the answer in the `Kotlin` slack channel. And to solve this particular issue add `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.5.0` instead of `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0`.

However, it is generally a good idea to learn a build system like `Gradle`or `Maven` and using those in the project. It makes life a lot easier.

Comment: How to do that? In Android Studio, I can add it by typing the library address directly in 'dependencies{}' of build.gradle. Navigating that deeply buried GUI only to type the same address is not convenient. Can't I type it directly in IntellJ as I do in AS?

Comment: Doesn't work. In the editor it does recognize the artifacts (e.g. runBlocking) but in the build time it doesn't. It says "Unresolved reference: kotlinx".

Comment: @AviTshuva It used to work but not sure why it isn't working anymore. Probably the latest version of Idea changed something. However, you can also use the shitty Gradle to add this dependency.