# Kotlin not importing coroutines in intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am new to Kotlin and intellij and am trying to test out coroutines. I have an issue where my project is not allowing me to import coroutines. I feel like the solution isn't that tough, but just haven't be able to do it myself. I have followed the instructions detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522282/using-kotlinx-coroutines-in-intellij-idea-project), but without any success. I have included links to images of how my project and its dependencies are setup here
[image: Kotlinx.coroutines not importing]

Coroutines not importing

[image: Dependencies tab]

Dependencies tab

If anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong, please let me know. Going forward what should I be doing?

Comment: Try to depend on `kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm` artifact, not on `kotlinx-coroutines-core`

Comment: I've also tried adding `jetbrains.kotlinx.coroutines.core.jvm` to the dependencies as well, but this does not yield results. Let me know if I should provide any more information that'd you'd think would be helpful

Comment: Ok... I tried to do what you said again and realized that I forgot a wildcard. Thus, I imported the jvm version and wrote `import kotlinx.coroutines.*` and it doesn't give me an error anymore. Thanks!