# IntelliJ: After adding coroutine, compilation failes with "unresolved reference: kotlinx"

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

After adding the library `jetbrains.kotlinx.coroutines.core.jvm`, the IDE seems to show coroutine-related classes in the auto-complete (first image below). However, building the source code below

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
}
```

fails with "Main.kt: (1, 8): Unresolved reference: kotlinx". Why is this so? I added the library in Project Settings -> Modules -> untilted3 (project name) and main (at first I added it to main, then I also added it untiled3) -> Dependencies, as the second image below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the external coroutines dependency. Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522282/using-kotlinx-coroutines-in-intellij-idea-project  . And it would be helpful to know if you are using a build tool.

Comment: @Augusto As you see above, I had already added the library, but that only made auto-complete work, not compilation.

Comment: Ops, I missed that. Looks like you are using gradle. Did you add the dependency in gradle too? As intellij is running gradle to compile the project rather than the intenal compiler.

Comment: @Augusto How do I add the dependency in Gradle? Actually, I had followed the same page that you linked above, and it did not say that I have to add it to Gradle.

Comment: Check this bit of the documentation: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#gradle . You need to check also which if you are using the groovy DSL or Kotlin DSL for gradle. You might already have a dependency block in your gradle file, otherwise add one... And a word of caution: Coroutines look really cool, but they are not that useful in server side development (they are useful for Android apps)

Comment: @Augusto I was just trying to test coroutine. Anyway, adding `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.0")` inside of `dependencies{}` in "build.gradle.kts", resolved the reference. I don't know the details about groovy or gradle (the are two different things?); all I know is that IntellJ uses it by default. Do I usually have to add a library in two places like this? It is really inconvenient.

Comment: No, just add it to gradle and then [sync intellij with gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-gradle/syncing-and-reloading/). About the DSLs, Gradle supports 2 languages for the build files. Groovy is the old one and Kotlin is the new one... I just mentioned this as it's super easy to copy/paste a solution in a build file and wonder for hours why it doesn't work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, as long as I know, this problem is due to a plugin that needs to be added to Gradle Project's file
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'